# How kanban view shakes when moving the cursor to it in odoo?

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-10, kanban

Once I have seen in a module, when I try to open a kanban view record, it just jiggles or dances. Can anybody tell me how to do that?

or

suggest me some interesting stuffs to do on a kanban view

Thank You!